# Android ConstraintLayout in java code set the percentage of sides ImageView object

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

**Screen:**

[image]

Good afternoon to everyone. I want to set the image to a ImageView size relative to the parent container as a percentage. But the size of the picture does not change.

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = new ConstraintLayout(this);
constraintLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());

ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

ImageView contactUs = new ImageView(this);
contactUs.setImageResource(R.drawable.rezgoriz);
contactUs.setId(View.generateViewId());
constraintLayout.addView(contactUs, 0);

set.clone(constraintLayout);

set.constrainPercentHeight(constraintLayout.getId(), 20);
set.constrainPercentWidth(constraintLayout.getId(), 20);

set.applyTo(constraintLayout);

setContentView(constraintLayout);
```

I'd appreciate any help. If anyone knows a publication in which is very detailed how to program in `ConstraintLayout` with good examples, I will also be grateful.

Comment: are you using android studio?

Comment: you can also assign a "weight" to your layout that will give you the same outcome of % check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48677839/how-to-add-different-weight-to-constraintlayout-views

Comment: and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782648/what-about-percentage-usage

Comment: Ruben Meiring, yes, using android studio.

Comment: okay then use the layout designer in android studio you going to have an easier time making the layouts with that than programatically putting them in

Comment: Reben, I need to understand why the code doesn't work.

Comment: Yes , I know what I am suggesting is to do it via the xml and not programtically

Answer (score 0):

You want the *ImageView* to be a percentage of the *ConstraintLayout's* height and width, so you need to target the *ImageView* (`contactus`) and not the *ConstraintLayout*. The value set also needs to be a float of 20% or `0.2f`:

```
set.constrainPercentHeight(contactUs.getId(), 0.2f);
set.constrainPercentWidth(contactUs.getId(), 0.2f);
```

Comment: Cheticamp, https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet, Sets the height of the view as a percentage of the parent.

Comment: @PvlPa That is correct, but which is the child view and which is the parent? I say the _ImageView_ is the child view and the _ConstraintLayout_ is the parent, so it is `set.constrainPercentHeight(contactUs.getId(), 0.2f)`  and not what you have. Am I missing something here?

Comment: your size is taken from a child view.